# How to add commas to output retrieved in XML.text?

Tags: javascript, xml, soap

Currently I'm using SOAP to retrieve my values. So the issue now is that

When i get a response it is in XML so in order to view the response,i did a response.responseText

So the code looks like this:

```
$.ajax(settings).complete(function (response) {
     console.log(response.responseText);
}
```

The response i get in the console.log is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:findResponse xmlns:ns="http://property.property.ws" xmlns:ax221="http://property.property.ws/xsd" xmlns:ax223="http://filter.common.nyx.nl/xsd">
            <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">48</ns:return>
            <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">50</ns:return>
            <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">51</ns:return>
        </ns:findResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If u scroll to the right you can see my three values 48 50 and 51.

So i want to extract the these 3 values. As of now I'm doing this:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.responseText);     
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

var primaryKeysOfProperties = $xml.text();

console.log(primaryKeysOfProperties);
```

The outcome i get from primaryKeysOfProperties is 485051.

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**
I want to get the output to be like this 48,50,51 instead.

I have been at this for 2 days now.. i researched and found some similar issues here in stack overflow but those are a little different. I tried to change but i failed. Anyone can help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the `result` array should contain what you are looking for

```
const xml = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:findResponse xmlns:ns="http://property.property.ws" xmlns:ax221="http://property.property.ws/xsd" xmlns:ax223="http://filter.common.nyx.nl/xsd">
            <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">48</ns:return>
            <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">50</ns:return>
            <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">51</ns:return>
        </ns:findResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

const xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
const $xml = $(xmlDoc);
const result = [];
$xml.find('ns\\:return').each(function(){
  result.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(result.join(','))
```

Comment: The response i get is blank. I tried to console.log (el) i get [object Object]